# How to get an image on top of another website

Tags: image, google-chrome, iframe

I'm trying to prototype a sort of torch that would 'light up' webpages. I've done this by placing a black image with a transparent hole in the middle, over a background.
I'm struggling to think of a way to post the code in a way that's tangible but here is the files (whole lot under 2mb, open in chrome): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1cyl710mmhtbo51/843TzPcuQ_

I'm now trying to replace the website backgrounds, which in my example are images, with real sites. I've tried iframes, but found that to be unsuccessful as you can't embed google etc.
Can anyone think of a way in which I could have my dark image hovering over a live website?

This only need work for the demo on my own laptop.

Comment: You could maybe use jquery to load a remote page into a div $('#div').load('http://example.com')?

Comment: I'm going to test this now Jake, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If it only needs to work on your machine, just copy the source of the page into an HTML file and save it. Then you can edit it any way you want. You may have to adjust URLs so that images and CSS work properly.

Comment: Not sure this is going to work with the variety of websites I'm hoping to demo over.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, anyway;
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/mkAYj/)

```
document.body.appendChild(lightContainer);
lightContainer.appendChild(light);
lightContainer.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var posX = e.clientX;
  var posY = e.clientY;
  light.style.left = -5000 + posX +'px';
  light.style.top = -5000 + posY + 'px';
};
```

You don't see anything underneath it because I couldn't find a transparent image.
In the content div you can place anything you want.